# Bundle and Deploy Perl Dancer Web App

Tags: perl, dancer

I have developed a simple web application.The problem is i have to deploy it on another machine.For that again i have to install dancer on that.Is there a way to bundle the app with dancer and then do the deployment ?

Comment: you may want to check Carton. and have a cpanfile file. more details: [http://advent.perldancer.org/2014/4](http://advent.perldancer.org/2014/4)